# Can premixed gases stratify inside a sealed chamber?

Tags: density, buoyancy, kinetic-theory, gas

Methane, which has a density of 0.65 $kg/m^3$, and air with 1.225$kg/m^3$ are mixed  in a chamber. If left undisturbed, will the mixture stratify due to the density difference, under normal gravity on earth? If so, in what order of the time scale can we expect such a stratification to occur? Lets assume, the chamber we are talking about is a *meter* tall.